# How to split a list into two lists by even and odd positions?

Tags: list, elm

I want to split a arbirtray list of elements by position into two new lists containing all the even and odd elements.

Example:
With a list like this:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

how can I get two lists like this:

```
(["a", "c", "e"], ["b", "d"])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Single pass and much less code:

```
evensAndOdds : List a -> (List a, List a)
evensAndOdds =
  List.foldr (\item (a, b) -> (item :: b, a)) ([], [])
```

The trick here is to switch the position of the elements of the returned tuple on each iteration, thereby alternating which one is appended to without having to keep track of the index.

Comment: clever, but the resulting lists are reversed from the original order

Comment: @MtnViewMark Did you actually check? It would if it used `foldl`, but this uses `foldr`.

Comment: Didn't look reversed to me when I checked

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:

```
evensAndOdds : List a -> (List a, List a)
evensAndOdds items
  let
    enum = List.indexedMap Tuple.pair items
    evens = List.filterMap (\(i, v) -> if modBy 2 i == 0 then Just v else Nothing) enum
    odds = List.filterMap (\(i, v) -> if modBy 2 i == 1 then Just v else Nothing) enum
  in
    (evens, odds)
```

Solution 2:

```
evensAndOdds : List a -> (List a, List a)
evensAndOdds =
  List.indexedMap (\i v -> (modBy 2 i == 0, v))
  >> List.partition Tuple.first
  >> Tuple.mapFirst (List.map Tuple.second)
  >> Tuple.mapSecond (List.map Tuple.second)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a recursive function. It may be easier to read than `fold`, especially for beginners.

```
evensAndOdds : List a -> ( List a, List a )
evensAndOdds input =
    case input of
        [] ->
            ( [], [] )

        [ even ] ->
            ( [ even ], [] )

        [ even, odd ] :: tail ->
            let
                ( tailEvens, tailOdds ) =
                    evensAndOdds tail
            in
            ( even :: tailEvens, odd :: tailOdds )
```